# Calling API every 20 Seconds and Stop on a Specific Response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect

I want to call my API every 20 seconds from the moment where the component is rendered and the api calling has to stop when it provides a specific response.

Explaining more. There is an API get method which will send a response like below.
**{firstWork : 'Success' , SecondWork : 'Success' , ThirdWork : 'IN-Progress'}**

So I want to call this API periodically/repeatedly(every 20sec) from the point where the Component is Rendered and till all these becomes 'Success'.
**{firstWork : 'Success' , SecondWork : 'Success' , ThirdWork : 'Success'}**

When I get the above response I should Stop calling the API get method. How can I achieve it in ReactJS?

Comment: Please include some code to show your component calling the api once

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by setting a `setInterval` inside your component.

```
import { useEffect } from "react"

const Component = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      fetch("/yourApiEndpoint")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          if(json.thirdWork === "Success"){
            clearInterval(interval)
          }
        })
    }, 20*1000)
  },[])

  return <p>component</p>
}
```

Comment: you don't need to, the interval starts right away, it's not a function, it holds a reference to the interval.